# Google Keep Printing

Tags: google-keep

I have been taking notes with Google Keep, but I cannot find any way to print. I cannot open the files in my Drive and there does not seem to be a print button. The Chrome file-print is greyed out. How do I print notes?

Comment: Are you using [drive.google.com/keep](https://drive.google.com/keep) to view them? Have you checked in Settings that your Google account is attached to Keep? Have you checked in system settings that sync is enabled?

Comment: Google Keep, at least for the desktop, is only partially baked. I'm not sure that the ability to print the notes is even part of their future plans. For what it's worth, I can print from the Android app using Cloud Print.

Answer (score 14):

Google Keep now allows you to convert a note, or a group of notes, to a single Google Doc.

As `Rubén` suggests in a comment to your question, the best way to go about printing a note (or notes) is to make a copy in Google Docs. Then, print it from there.

---

Here's how:

1. Copy to Google Doc

[image: Copy to Google Doc from Keep Note]

2. Open Google Doc

[image: Open Google Doc]

3. Print Google Doc

[image: Print Google Doc]

---

Here's how you do this with a group of notes.

[image: GIF]

Comment: how do you select hundreds of notes in one go?

Comment: @Thufir If you've tagged your notes with a label, you can navigate the notes within that label and select all with your keyboard (Ctrl A or Cmd A).

Comment: Thank you for going to the extra effort of posting screenshots! The visual learners among us appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copying to Google docs and printing from there works well for me, especially for printing multiple notes, per rahi's post above.
2. Highlighting what you want to print and then right clicking and selecting print, also works well, but doesn't get the title if you have a title on your Google-keep-note, per robin smith post above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to print one or several Notes from KEEPS:

- be sure to organize all your notes by using LABELS
- Go to the Label that has the note
- Select one or select all notes with CTRL-A
- Go to the Top Right Corner an click on the 3 dops
- Select "Copy to Google Docs"
- view the file on open "Google Docs" and then printed the note
  [image]

Answer (score -1):

How to print in Keep?  Simple, highlight and print it (right mouse button).

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP had in mind.